# Cypress runner does not start when In run npx cypress open command from within Visual studio Code terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code, cypress

I'm currently learning Cypress and I created a new folder for my project and did the following:

1.npm init - where i initialised node (before this I have opened the new folder of course)
2.npm install cypress --save-dev
3.npx cypress open (this time opened my Cypress runner, no problem here...yet)
4.Selected E2E Testing
5.On Configuration files page clicked "Continue"
6.Selected Electron as browser option
7.On the Create your first spec window clicked "Create new spec" - to create the initial template
8.closed the Cypress runner / Cypress

Note: I have updated Cypress to the latest version

Problem: When I run the npx cypress open command my Cypress runner does not open at all, please can someone help me out with this? Thanks!

I will include a screenshot with what I have right now in VS code.
[image]

Comment: What happens if you do instead `npm run cypress open` in the project directory?

Comment: Hi thanks for coming back on this issue of mine, if I run this command in my VS code terminal i get this error: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/gheorgheberes/.npm/_logs/2024-03-28T12_12_11_390Z-debug-0.log
gheorgheberes@xxxx-MacBook-Pro Real-App-Project % npm run cypress open
npm ERR! Missing script: "cypress"
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To see a list of scripts, run:
npm ERR!   npm run

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/gxxxx/.npm/_logs/2024-03-28T12_12_50_088Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Try changing the "test" script in package.json to `"test": "cypress open"` then do `npm run test`

Comment: Hi Adsy, I did change it but again it does not open Cypress at all

Comment: {
  "name": "realapp-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "cypress open"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^13.7.1"
  }
}

Comment: This is the reponse in my VS code terminal:       > realapp-project@1.0.0 test
> cypress open

Comment: I'm following a guy called Artem Bondar ojn Udemy, but from what I see he did not change anything in he's package.json file at all and interestignly he's Cypress opens but not mine and I have also have updated my Cypress to the latest version

Comment: Yeh, just trying to get a new entry point (its equivalent) and rule out an NPX issue. Lets now change the `test` script to `"test": "DEBUG=cypress:* cypress open"` to enable cypresses verbose logging and do `npm run test` again. I assume you are on osx/linux? If windows, this will need to be slightly diff.

Comment: I'm on MacOS (macbook pro)I have changed the test and ran the command  but  this is what I have in my terminal:     > realapp-project@1.0.0 test
> DEBUG=cypress:* cypress open

Comment: cypress:cli:cli cli starts with arguments ["/usr/local/bin/node","/Users/gheorgheberes/Desktop/RealApp-Project/node_modules/.bin/cypress","open"] +0ms
  cypress:cli NODE_OPTIONS is not set +0ms
  cypress:cli:cli program parsing arguments +4ms
  cypress:cli:cli opening Cypress +1ms

Comment: Just got this response now (bit slow though not sure why)

Comment: Hmm so its stuck on opening cypress. I dont suppose you have any anti virus software installed? This is quite similiar to if there is OS level blocking on the binary. Also try `sudo npm run test` to see if that helps.

Comment: ONe thing that comes to mind is sometimes you need to go into OSX system preferences "privacy" section and click allow on the prompt in there since it is a binary downloaded from the web.

Comment: Cypress then says this (tons of error) says it's an issue with my config file lol

Comment: It threw an error when required, check the stack trace below:

Stack trace
Error: ECANCELED: operation canceled, read
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:453:20)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1397:18)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)

Comment: at Object. (/Users/gheorgheberes/Desktop/RealApp-Project/node_modules/listr2/dist/listr.js:4:14)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)

Comment: at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object. (/Users/gheorgheberes/Desktop/RealApp-Project/node_modules/listr2/dist/index.js:13:14)

Comment: at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object. (/Users/gheorgheberes/Desktop/RealApp-Project/node_modules/cypress/lib/tasks/verify.js:7:5)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)

Comment: Ah ok, getting somewhere! Can you edit your original question with the cypress config file?

Comment: Also can you paste the part of the error that indicates a problem with the config file?

Comment: This is all the errors I have in the cypress runner when it opens up, for the config file

Comment: I did not install any antivirus on my mac I just has the firewall / default setting on also when I first started using Cypress it worked though opened every-time so fast without no issues have no idea what this is which is quite frustrating

Comment: I've made a screen recording I have deleted the old project folder then created a brand new one and took the same exact config steps to set the test framework up as I saw in the course:   https://vimeo.com/928466348/1dd2a8603c?share=copy

Comment: Also what does this mean though? DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:51441/devtools/browser/7949b26b-8e0f-42aa-96e5-fc206e01d245
2024-03-28 16:42:27.026 Cypress[12121:245629] WARNING: Secure coding is not enabled for restorable state! Enable secure coding by implementing NSApplicationDelegate.applicationSupportsSecureRestorableState: and returning YES.

Comment: Dont worry about the waning - not related. When you first started editing the config, it had a syntax error. You fixed this in the process of adding more config and saved the file. However the Cypress process that was still running was still open. You need to kill that cypress process. You open a new terminal and try to open cypress again -- that probs wont work. You should only have 1 terminal with an active cypress process in. What you have now looks ok in the config. But kill everything, make sure no cypress process is running (even kill vscode and run `killall -9 node` in a osx terminal).

Comment: Essentially, changing the config may require cypress restart. And you don't want to open more than 1 cypress process. You need to kill all cypress/node/electron processes (reboot if you want -- and say no to osx restoring processes/apps on reboot) and start cypress again. Sometimes this happens if you get an orphaned process that is stuck. Actually this would explain an awful lot.

Comment: Hi I think I made a mistake and just confused myself I did not copy and paste the right specPattern that caused that issue I figured it out, but many thanks for your help!!!